# $e^{1.5\pi i}$ returns different answers on different calculators

Tags: complex-numbers

I have been trying to solve this math problem, but I get different answers from different calculators.

$e^{1.5\pi i}$

WolframAlpha returns $-1.i$

My graphing calculator returns $-i$

Why are there different answers for the same problem?

Comment: $-1.i = -i$  ...

Comment: Use 3/2 instead of 1.5 in Alpha.

Comment: @user2520938: In fact the dot _is_ a decimal point; the number is $-1.$ multiplied by $i$.

Comment: @TonyK Ah oke sorry, my bad. I still think that the OPs confusion stems from reading the $.$ as a decimal point though (although $1.i$ doesn't make sense of course), since I doubt they wouldn't understand that $-1\cdot i =-i$

Comment: Are you serious ?

Answer (score 2):

You have entered input as a $1.5$, so Wolfram alpha evaluates this numerically and returns numerical result $-1.i=-1.00000 \cdot i = -i$. If you want the exact answer, enter `e^((3/2 pi)i)`.